# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Get a List of Models and then get the Model Columns - options for this

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

ASP.NET Core 2.0  Get a List of Models and then get the Model Columns - What are my options for this?. There are 2 key items that I'm trying to accomplish. 1. Get a list of Models from ApplicationDBContext with GetModels(). This part works fine and I get a list of models. 2. Get a list of Columns from a Model with GetModelColumns and passing the the modelName as a string. How do I get the results for PropertyInfo?

Since I cannot instatiate a new PropertyInfo() should I use typeof ?

using System.Reflection;

```
    public static List<PropertyInfo> GetModels()
    {
        //Get the list of Models in ApplicationDbContext
        var propertyInfoList = typeof(ApplicationDbContext).GetProperties().ToList();
        return propertyInfoList;
    }

    public static PropertyInfo GetModelColumns(string modelName)
    {
        //return the Columns associated with the Model
    //How should this be done?
        //Cannot instatiate a new PropertyInfo()
        //Use typeof?           
        var propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        var propertyInfoList = GetModels();
        propertyInfo = propertyInfoList.Single(s => s.Name == modelName);
        return propertyInfo;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> DetailsAsync(string? modelName)
    {
    string strColumnName="";
    var myModel = GetModelColumns(modelName));
    foreach(var item in myModel)
        {
           strColumnName=item.Name; 
        }
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working here? You can't say it's "not working" and then expect us to guess the problem I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm looking for coding options for GetModels(). The code in this does not work. It's only a sample of how I think it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this slightly differently. There's no point getting all of the properties of your context when you only want a single model. Secondly, the property type is going to be a `DbSet<T>` so you need to get the generic type. So you can do something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetColumns<TEntity>(string modelName)
{
    var property = typeof(TEntity)
        .GetProperties()
        .Single(s => s.Name == modelName);

    return property.PropertyType
        .GetGenericArguments() //Get the generic type of the DbSet
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties()
            .Select(pi => pi.Name));
}
```

You should probably put some type checking and validation on this, but this could be called like this:

```
var columns = GetColumns<ApplicationDbContext>("SomeProperty");
```